# Angular mess with observables and behaviorsubject. Can't figured out the proper way to refactor my code

Tags: angular, rxjs

I know this title is a little vague, but I am gonna explain with a Service of mine.

Basically, I have this application wide service that I can use to set a source from a list of sources I fetch from my backend, and various parts of my app use said source.

When the user first enters my website and has not yet selected a source, I want to set it as the first source in the list fetched from my server.
Once the user changes the selected source I store his choice in the browser storage so when he comes back I can load it back.

This was all working fine, but the new feature I want to add is that I want to make it possible to send a link with say "*?source=abc*" and then when someone opens it, I override the current source to that value.

Here is my code:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SourceService {
    private apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
    private sources = new BehaviorSubject<Map<string, Source>>(new Map<string, Source>());
    private source = new BehaviorSubject<Source>(null);
    private sourceOverride: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.http.get<Source[]>(this.apiUrl + "/sources").subscribe(
            sources => {
                const sourceMap = new Map<string, Source>();
                sources.forEach(source => sourceMap.set(source.id, source));
                this.sources.next(sourceMap);
            }
        );
    }

    overrideSourceById(sourceId: string): void {
        this.sourceOverride = sourceId;
    }

    getSource(): Observable<Source> {
        if (this.sourceOverride) {
            const sourceOverride = this.sourceOverride;
            this.sourceOverride = null;
            return this.getSourceById(sourceOverride).pipe(mergeMap(source => {
                this.setSource(source);
                return this.getSource();
            }));
        } else if (!this.source.getValue()) {
            return this.sources.pipe(mergeMap(sourceMap => {
                const historySourceId = localStorage.getItem('source');
                if (historySourceId) {
                    const historySource = sourceMap.get(historySourceId);
                    if (historySource) {
                        this.setSource(historySource);
                    } else {
                        this.setSource(sourceMap.get(sourceMap.keys().next().value));
                    }
                } else {
                    this.setSource(sourceMap.get(sourceMap.keys().next().value));
                }
                return this.getSource();
            }));
        }
        return this.source;
    }

    setSource(source: Source): void {
        localStorage.setItem("source", source.id);
        this.source.next(source);
    }

    getAvailableSources(): Observable<Source[]> {
        return this.sources.pipe(skip(1)).pipe(map(sources => Array.from(sources.values())));
    }

    getSourceById(id: string): Observable<Source> {
        return this.sources.pipe(skip(1)).pipe(map(sources => sources.get(id))).pipe(first());
    }
}
```

Other then looking wrong I am having problems synchronizing everything.

For instance, I have some pages that uses the method *getSourceById* to fetch the currently selected source, read a particular field of it, and then generate a url for an *img* tag.

The order of things is throwing me off. Sources are being read before they are actually populated and so on.

What can I do to improve this?

Comment: Only the addition of *?source=abc* is causing issues? Without it all works perfectly?

Comment: Not exactly. What I meant was that the whole code seemed "off". Introducing a new feature (the one where I can pass the path parameter to load a source) broke everything BECAUSE it all seems too fragile. My question is, given this scenario, what would be a better way to implement it? How can I work with all this async stuff properly?

Comment: I'm working on it.... from first glance I don't see why there's so much code with Observables here. Once you fetch the sources from the server, all else can be in sync mode. I'm looking...

Comment: See my Stackblitz project that is similar to yours, using in-memory data: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sources. Let me know if it helps (and if it answers your question) and I'll add an answer below with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly because you are using the wrong Subject. To give a quick rundown.

- Subject - Essentially a message pump. Does not have a "memory" of previous emits.
- ReplaySubject - Similar to Subject but will immediately pump X amount of previous emits on subscription.
- BehaviorSubject - Similar to Replay Subject, but will only emit *ONE* previous event, but also must have a default value.

More reading here : https://tutorialsforangular.com/2020/12/12/subject-vs-replaysubject-vs-behaviorsubject/

Anyway, here's what I notice :

```
private source = new BehaviorSubject<Source>(null);
```

This code means that if anyone subscribes to this, they will immediately receive a *null* value. Is this expected? I think not because :

```
getSourceById(id: string): Observable<Source> {
    return this.sources.pipe(skip(1)).pipe(map(sources => sources.get(id))).pipe(first());
}
```

I presume the skip here is because you were getting a null value correct? So you thought, well if I skip the first event (the null), then I'm good to go. But as soon as you emit another event via sources, you are now skipping legitimate data.

Here's what I would try :

- Change all BehaviourSubjects to ReplaySubject(1). That means it returns the last piece of data always, but will not have a default emission of null.
- Remove your skips. You are only skipping because you are using BehaviourSubjects and you don't want the default value. But if you swap to ReplaySubject, you no longer need to skip.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nearly identical implementation that might be useful for you (working [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sources)). It simplifies your implementation IMHO and takes into account all the scenarios. It may be further optimized, but the general code is simple enough to understand.

Notice that as a practice, subjects should be exposed to their consumers as Observables. In this example, the selected source is a `private source = new BehaviorSubject<number>(null);`, and the component sees the public `selectedSource$ = this.source.asObservable();`.

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class SourceService {
  private sources = new BehaviorSubject<Map<string, number>>(new Map<string, number>());
  private source = new BehaviorSubject<number>(null);
  private sourceOverride: string;
  private allSources = new Map<string, number>();

  selectedSource$ = this.source.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    of([1, 2, 3, 4]).subscribe(sources => {
      const sourceMap = new Map<string, number>();

      sources.forEach(source => sourceMap.set(source.toString(), source));
      this.sources.next(sourceMap);

      const savedSourceAsString = localStorage.getItem('source');

      if (savedSourceAsString) {
        const savedSource = parseInt(savedSourceAsString);

        if (isNaN(savedSource)) {
          this.setSource(sources[0]);
        } else {
          this.setSource(savedSource);
        }
      } else {
        this.setSource(sources[0]);
      }
    });

    this.source
      .subscribe()
  }

  setSource(source: number): void {
    localStorage.setItem("source", source.toString());
    this.source.next(source);
  }

  getAvailableSources(): Observable<number[]> {
    return this.sources
      .pipe(map(sources => Array.from(sources.values())));
  }
}
```

**Component template:**

```
<div>
  <h4>All Sources with an option to select any one of them:</h4>
  <div *ngFor="let source of allSources$ | async">
    <button (click)="overrideSource(source)">Select source {{ source }}</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <h4>Currently selected source: {{ selectedSource$| async }}</h4>
</div>
```

**Component class:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { SourceService } from './source.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  allSources$ = this.sourceService.getAvailableSources();
  selectedSource$ = this.sourceService.selectedSource$;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private sourceService: SourceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(async params => {
          const sourceAsString = params.source as string;

      if (sourceAsString) {
        const source = parseInt(sourceAsString);

        if (!isNaN(source)) {
          this.sourceService.setSource(source);
        }
      }
         });
}

  overrideSource(source: number): void {
    this.sourceService.setSource(source);
  }
}
```